# Do large objects follow Schrödinger equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

I have read here that double slit experiment can be performed on molecules.

> Matter-wave interference with particles selected from a molecular
>   library with masses exceeding 10000 amu
>
> https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.8343

Does it mean that large objects like planets also follow Schrödinger equation? Can they also appear somewhere else (few mm, cm or km or more) with some very low probability? I mean probability might be so low that statistically it can be more than time till end of the universe.

But can it happen?

Edit: Please let me know if my understanding is wrong. And what is actually possible for large objects.

Comment: 4 orders of magnitude get you to a mesoscopic object, which might maintain coherence, and could thus QM-interfere. 28 orders of magnitude for a Mack truck would not, so if somebody  talked about Mack truck interference, take flight, as he's probably a philosopher.

Comment: In principle, yes. The point isn't how large the object is, the point is how isolated it is. If you are really talking about a large isolated object, sure, it is certainly quantum mechanical. But, if you are talking about an open system then decoherence takes over and the object behaves classically.

Comment: The largest quantum object I've heard about is a LIGO mirror: https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2017/02/ligo-doesn-t-just-detect-gravitational-waves-it-makes-them-too and https://conservancy.umn.edu/bitstream/handle/11299/96092/1/Mavalvala.pdf